# How can I use a zk-chart on click?

Tags: charts, zk

I have a great problem with ZK charts!
I have 2 type of chart: a chart with data of the current day (so this chart is generated automatically) and a chart with data of a clicked date.

The first chart works correctely, the second not! 
If I have clicked on a date, I build a graph! But it's impossible to modify the label position or name of label! And I need to modify these things. This is my graph:

```
<charts width="1700" style="height: 400px" type="line" model="@bind(vm.chart2)" title="">
</charts>
```

When I clicked I call this method:

```
@Command
@NotifyChange("chart2")
public ChartsModel viewGraph(@BindingParam("self") Group self){
        String a = self.getLabel();//this is for passed a parameter 
        ServiceImpl usr = new ServiceImpl();
        chart2 = usr.viewGraph(a);
        return chart2;

    }
```

viewGraph is so built:

```
@Override
    public ChartsModel viewGraph(String data) {
        //chart2 = new Charts();


        chart2.setModel(LineLabelsData.setCategoryModel2(data));        
        chart2.getXAxis().getLabels().setRotation(180);
        chart2.getYAxis().getTitle().setText("TEXT");        
        chart2.getTooltip().setEnabled(false);
        chart2.getXAxis().getLabels().setRotation(180);      

        LinePlotOptions linePlotOptions =
                chart2.getPlotData().getPlotOptions().getLine();
        linePlotOptions.setEnableMouseTracking(false);
        linePlotOptions.getDataLabels().setEnabled(true);

        return chart2.getModel();

    }
```

If I print something in this method my console view it correctely! The problem is that

```
chart2.getYAxis().getTitle().setText("TEXT");
```

does not work like

```
chart2.getXAxis().getLabels().setRotation(180);
```

How can I change that values?

Answer (score 0):

To change yAxis title, you can simply call chart2.getYAxis().setTitle("title");

You may want to post your questions in [ZK Forum](http://forum.zkoss.org/questions/) rather than stackoverflow as our community users are experienced in ZK, and can help you quicker.